# Android layout:weight doesn't work on device

Tags: android, layout

I'm getting two differents behavior for a ListActivity row. Eclipse Graphical Layout show the right behavior, but at runtime, on the device, the *layout:weight* doesn't seem to work properly and the Textview is resized to the minimum width, depending on the text property.

This is how I had setup the layout.

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp" 
    android:background="@color/defaultBg" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">

   <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" 
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

   <TextView
           android:id="@+id/myText"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_margin="5dp"
           android:background="#2288EE"
           android:layout_weight="6" android:text="Hello" android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: **I just found that the LinearLayout doesn't fill the listRow width. I'm still trying to find how to solve**

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: change width of your `textView and ImageView` with `fill_parent`

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem.. Instead I read many post where is suggested to set the layout:width to '0dp' while using layout:weight property.

Comment: @MauroNonnis Your problem is solved or not?

Comment: No Dipak. I add only an update. Anyway I'm thinking that I have to set up the List Row to stretch the entire width. I only Inflated the row layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix the issue myself. The problem wasn't in the table row layout posted above. The problem was in the android:layout_width of the parent ListView which was set to 'wrap_content' instead of 'fill_parent'.

Thanks to everyone who offered his contribute!

Comment: Indeed this was correct, try to mark it as the correct answer please =)

Answer (score 0):

In your `LinearLayout` put `android:weightSum="8"`. It should do the trick, on my device works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this doesn't fix the issue for me

Comment: Please post the entire layout.

Comment: What you see is the entire layout. I just test the app on the emulator and I get the same unexpected layout as on the device. Furthermore, in the code I disabled all operations over the gui components.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding android:scaleType="fitCenter" to your ImageButton. If I'm not mistaken, your source Drawable is too big, therefore making the ImageButton take too much horizontal space.

Comment: No Tas, as I wrote the problem is about the TextView which left unused space on its right. The ImageButton instead take the expected space.